# Reduce brightness on external monitor in Wayland in 17.10

Tags: multiple-monitors, 17.10, brightness, external-monitor, wayland

I used to be able to control the brightness of my external monitor using `xrandr`.
How do I do this with Wayland? The brightness control in the upper-right corner does not do this. */sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness* does not do this.